# Mongoose schema for array of objects and upon update objects should get added

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = mongoose.model('GridModel',  {  
    Request_Id : { type : Number, required : true },    
    viewStudents : { type : Array , default : [] }
});
```

The above one is the mongoose model and after update to the viewStudents fileds should get added.

Query for update is :

```
var conditions = { Request_Id : req.body.Request_Id},
    update = {  
       viewStudents : {   
         Student_Name:req.body.Student_Name,
         Student_Id:req.body.Student_Id,
         Resume:req.body.Resume}
    },
    options = { multi : true};

GridModel.update(conditions, update, options, callback);

function callback(err,res2) {
    if(err)
        res.send(err);
    getGridRequests(res);
}
```

Final output after two updates should look like

```
viewStudents: {
    {
         Student_Name: asa,
         Student_Id : 3,
         Resume : No
    } 
    {
        Student_Name: asfsdfa,
        Student_Id : 34234,
        Resume : No
    }
}
```

But I am not getting the way I have shown with the above code

Comment: You need to use $set

Comment: Does object with `Request_Id` already exist in db?

Comment: Sorry, I missed adding Request_Id field in GridModel while posting this. Now I have added that field.

Answer (score 0):

GridModel has no `Request_Id` property. Update should have `$push` modificator:

```
{  
    viewStudents : {
        $push: {
            Student_Name:req.body.Student_Name,
            Student_Id:req.body.Student_Id,
            Resume:req.body.Resume
        }
    }
}
```

*NOTE* Upper camel case with underscores looks very strange to me.